# How can I add buyable features to my Android app (in a specific way)?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an Android app which is represented by the following picture:

[image: Main activity appearence]

The main activity is a sort of "main menu" composed of buttons. Each button starts a sub-activity. All is working fine so far, this is not the purpose of this question.

What I would like to do is adding some features in time. For example, I add a new feature/activity to my project and I would like my main activity to become like so:

[image: Added features appearence]

So my main activity would have more buttons now. Each new button should act as described below:

- **If the feature is free**, simply act as a normal button (like the ones that were provided with the published activity)
- **If the feature must be bought to be used**, the button (once clicked) would show a "temporary" activity which will provide a video presentation of the new feature and the option to buy it or not.

  - **If the user does not buy** the new feature, it should remain the same as long as the new feature is not bought (so the button will always show the "temporary" activity).
  - **If the user buys** the new feature, the button should now launch the new feature instead of the "temporary" activity.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible? (I guess yes but it doesn't hurt to ask...)
2. How can I implement this as easilly as possible (I took a look at the in-app billing feature and example, but it's a little bit confusing as my app does not work exactly the same, due to the "temporary" activity thing...)

If you have any idea/suggestion that could help, I would be glad to hear it!

Comment: Your case is absolutely standard, your "temporary" activity does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use any in-app libraries. Just use some flags to indicate what feature is free and what is payable. To check what feature was bought, just use standard Google in-app methods from [example app](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) and here is [in-app implementation guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) with implementation details.